# Is "Escherian metamorphosis" always possible?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, tiling

$\DeclareMathOperator\int{int}\DeclareMathOperator\diam{diam}\DeclareMathOperator\area{area}\DeclareMathOperator\cl{cl}\DeclareMathOperator\ran{ran}\DeclareMathOperator\dom{dom}$*This is a tweaked version of a question which was asked and bountied [at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4555946/28111); that question still hasn't quite been answered, but suggestions in the comments convinced me that this was the "right" version to ask instead:*

This question is motivated by Escher's series of **Metamorphosis** woodcuts (see e.g. [here](https://www.escherinhetpaleis.nl/story-of-escher/metamorphosis-i-ii-iii/?lang=en)), where one tesselating tile is gradually transformed into another. Basically, this is a precise way of asking the following: can we always "metamorphose" between any pair of tesselating shapes?

First, some definitions (everything is in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual metric):

- A *shape* is a compact connected set $X$ with $X=\cl(\int(X))$.
- A *tiling* is a pair $(\mathscr{S},F)$ where $\mathscr{S}$ is a finite set of shapes and $F$ is a set of functions such that

  - each $f\in F$ is an isometric embedding of some $S\in\mathscr{S}$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$,
  - $\bigcup_{f\in F}\ran(f)=\mathbb{R}^2$, and
  - if $f,g\in F$ are distinct with domains $S,T$ respectively and $x\in \int(S)$, then $f(x)\not\in \ran(g)$ ("shapes only meet at their boundaries").
- A *tile* is a shape $X$ such that $(\{X\},F)$ is a tiling for some $F$.
- $d_H$ is [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance). *(Note that we could replace $d_H$ with the modified version $d_{H*}(U,V)$ = the infimum over planar isometries $p$ of $d_H(p(U), V)$ without changing the question substantively; all that would change is that the number of tiles needed would shrink, but I'm not looking at that here.)*

Now with apologies to Escher, given tiles $A,B$ and $\epsilon>0$ let a **strong $\epsilon$-metamorphism** from $A$ to $B$ be a tiling $(\mathscr{S},F)$ such that

- if $f\in F$ and $(x,y)\in \ran(f)$ with $x<0$ then $\dom(f)=A$,
- there is some $N$ such that if $g\in F$ and $(x,y)\in \ran(g)$ with $x>N$ then $\dom(g)=B$ (call the least such $N$ the *length* of the $\epsilon$-metamorphism), and
- if $f,g\in F$ and $\ran(f)\cap \ran(g)\not=0$ then $$d_H(\dom(f), \dom(g))<\epsilon\cdot {\area_f+\area_g\over 2},$$ where $\area_j$ is the area of the domain of $j$ for $j\in F$. (This "scaling" of the Hausdorff distance means that we can't trivialize things by shrinking. This should have been included in the original problem, but I forgot it.)

Finally, say that an **$\epsilon$-metamorphism** is as above but with the final inequality having right hand side merely $\epsilon$.

> **Question 1**: Is there always a strong $\epsilon$-metamorphism between $A$ and $B$ for any tiles $A,B$ and any positive $\epsilon$?

I recall seeing a theorem that the answer is **yes**, and that moreover we can always find metamorphisms with length "close to" the naive guess $${\max\{\diam(A),\diam(B)\}\cdot d_H(A,B)\over \epsilon},$$ but I haven't been able to track it down or prove it myself. I'm also interested in whether the situation changes as we appropriately tweak things to work in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n>2$.

> **Question 2**: Assuming for the moment that $\epsilon$-metamorphisms always exist (which seems plausible based on the comments at the MSE version of this question), what can we say about the length function $$\mathscr{l}_{A,B}: \epsilon\mapsto\inf\{N: \mbox{an $\epsilon$-metamorphism from $A$ to $B$ with length $N$ exists}\}$$ for a pair of tiles $A,B$? In particular, what is $\mathscr{l}_{\mbox{unitsquare, unithexagon}}$?

Comment: Interesting question!

Comment: Which of the Escher images do you find most suggestive for an answer about unit squares and unit hexagons?

Comment: @MattF. *Metamorphosis II* has a portion that goes squares-lizards-hexagons, I believe.